# Adding Aria-labels to Angular pagination grid to make it more accessible

Tags: angularjs, pagination, accessibility, screen-readers

In [this plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/81fPZxpnOQnIHQgp957q?p=preview) I borrowd from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs), there is an awesome example of how to create a pagination grid using AngularJs. 
(My question differs a bit from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370606/aria-and-pagination).)

In one of our projects, we have a quite similar solution, but in order to get some help, I will use the code from the plunker I mentioned above.

**My goal**: I'd like to make the pagination grid at the bottom more accessible to screen readers This is done by adding some aria-labels to the buttons of the grid, such as

```
aria-label="Go to first page"
aria-label="Go to previous page"
aria-label="Go to page 3"
```

And so on. How do I accomplish that?

Finally, here's the code:

**Template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todos">

  <head>
   <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.1" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js">    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TodoController">
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <h4>{{todos.length}} total</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in filteredTodos">{{todo.text}}</li>
    </ul>
    <pagination 
      ng-model="currentPage"
      total-items="todos.length"
      max-size="maxSize"  
      boundary-links="true">
    </pagination>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
var todos = angular.module('todos', ['ui.bootstrap']);

todos.controller('TodoController', function($scope) {
   $scope.filteredTodos = []
  ,$scope.currentPage = 1
  ,$scope.numPerPage = 10
  ,$scope.maxSize = 5;

  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $scope.todos = [];
    for (i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
      $scope.todos.push({ text:'todo '+i, done:false});
    }
  };
  $scope.makeTodos(); 

  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
  });
});
```

Comment: hi @Ilias, you can use the uib-pagination for angular. Also add ngAria.js from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria. Then your control elements will automatically be taken care by ngAria. In this case, the screen reader will read 1,2 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

First, let me preface by saying I've never used or looked at angular.  Do you have your own copy of angular?  Just poking around, the pagination element seems to be generated from a template in [template/pagination/pagination.html](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/pagination/pagination.html).  When I look at that source, it has stuff like

```
<li role="menuitem" ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-next">
   <a href ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" ng-disabled="noNext()||ngDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('next')}}
   </a>
</li>
```

Are you allowed to modify the templates?  If so, you could add an aria-label to the `<a>` and even get its text the same way, from paginationConfig.

I found this by poking around [ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js) from your plunker example.

Comment: Hi @slugolicious, I can change the template but I won't change the min.js file.

Comment: That sounds like a build issue.  You'd have to work with how you're building your project and bundling files together.

Comment: yes, the template can be changed with the template-url attribute on the angular pagination.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your `ui-bootstrap` version, if possible.

Library is right now at v2.4.0 and supports overriding pagination template since v0.14.0

After that, override default template for [pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination) using `template-url`.

> template-url (Default: uib/template/pagination/pagination.html) -
>   Override the template for the component with a custom provided
>   template

1. Copy default template in your code base
2. Modify it as you wish
3. Add `template-url` with file path to your `<pagination>` tag.

PS: Default pagination template is [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/pagination/pagination.html); Take care to refer docs and template of the version of library you are using.

**Edit:**
Sample from my code using `template-url` (ui-bootstrap v2.1.4):

```
<div class="text-center">
   <ul uib-pagination
     total-items="vm.totalCount"
     data-ng-if="vm.totalCount"
     ng-model="vm.page"
     items-per-page="vm.limit"
     boundary-links="true"
     max-size="3"
     template-url="app/core/components/pagination/pagination.html">
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this idea will work. Thank you @Sangharsh. Since the bounty will expire today, I wanted to give you points :). I will mark it correct once it works.

Comment: somehow my pagination is not shown anymore. I added a template in `view/pagination.html`. And added the `template-url` in my pagination. It seems that the pagination.html is being loaded. However, the pagination is not visible anymore. This is what I have now for pagination: `<uib-pagination ng-change="pageChanged()" ng-show="bigTotalItems > 10" template-url="view/util/pagination.html" rotate="false" total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" ...>`

Comment: `uib-pagination` directive is restricted to attributes (`restrict: 'A'`). Please use it with some tag e.g. `<ul>`.

Comment: Any errors on browser console? Also, which version of UI Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: there is no error on the browser console. I am using bootstrap version Version: 1.3.2

Comment: Glad I could get the ball rolling and contribute the initial idea as well as find the template that needs to be modified and the change required.